# How do I add button in NetSuite client script and use it as trigger for script function?

Tags: netsuite, suitescript2.0

I'm trying to add a button to the current record with the Client Script button definition on a script record, but for some reason it's not finding my function. I'm returning my function `tryThis`and there is a button on the page which I created on the script record with the function `tryThis` defined in the appropriate field, but the code doesn't run.  Here's my script:

```
define (['N/currentRecord','N/search','N/record'] ,
function(currentRecord,search,record) {
    function tryThis(context){
        log.debug({
            title: 'try this', 
            details: 'try this'
            });         
    }
    function pageInit(context) {
    } 

    return {
        pageInit: pageInit,
        tryThis: tryThis
    };
});
```

Nothing happens :(

Yes, the script is deployed.

[image]

How can I use this button on a client script??

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This doesn't exactly answer your question directly, but I hope it may help.  I tested this, and there appears to be nothing wrong with the way you've set it up - the only thing that seems to be not working is the `log` module, which I've come across before in client scripts.

Try running your function using a `console.log()` or `alert()` instead (both work for me).

Hopefully someone with more detailed knowledge of the `N/log` module's design and behavior will chip in, as the documentation seems to indicate that this should work.

Comment: Wow. You were exactly right. log.debug isn't working. When I use console.log() it works great.

Answer (score 0):

At the bottom of your Client Script record in Edit mode you will find where you can easily set the button and function to call.
[image]

Comment: Also, you didn't say in your statement if you're adding the client script via the user event or as a separate client script. Logging should work just fine on client scripts, as a separate client script record, not when added using the user event script.